# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < occurring when deploying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, router

Have a react app using react router with node/express server on the backend, I'm trying to deploy to heroku, but it is giving me this error...

'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <'

I believe it is my 'catch all' route in my express server which is serving up index.html.. not exactly sure... Here is a bit of my server file..

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const db = require('../database/index.js');
const passport = require('passport');
const helpers = require('./helpers.js');//eslint-disable-line
require('../server/config/passport')(passport);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../client/dist')));
app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(require('express-session')({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_PASSWORD || 'supersecretsecret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.end();
});

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../client/dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Here is my index.jsx file for the front end..

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import Home from './components/homepage.jsx';
import ArtistRegister from './components/artistregister.jsx';
import VenueRegister from './components/venueregister.jsx';
//import Test from './components/test.jsx';
import reducer from './reducers/index.js';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router- 
dom';//eslint-disable-line

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

const Base = ({ store }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/artistregister" component={ArtistRegister} 
        />
        <Route exact path="/venueregister" component={VenueRegister} />
        {/* <Route path="/artist/:username" component={Test} /> */}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<Base store={store} />, 
  document.getElementById('app'));
  };

store.subscribe(render);
render();
```

any help?

Comment: You need to transpile the JSX into Javascript, either before you push to the server or, have a a `postinstall` script that runs the build.

Comment: Ok i will look into that, but is there a reason why this wouldn't work on heroku when it is locally??

Comment: because I have never had this issue before, I assumed the jsx was automatically transpiled with webpack.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! it was transpiling correctly using babel, the only issue was that when deploying, my bundle.js was in the git-ignore.